# Give file and its line number to convert the hexadecimal number in decimal in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file of more than 10,000 lines. In this file I have a line number 713 contains three hexadecimal number like, `7E 42 C0`. I need to convert this to decimal. My code works well if I give only this number in a text file. But, I want to give the file and the line number of this file

Like in the following:

```
while read p q r; 
  do 

   printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x$p 0x$q 0x$r; 

 done   < $(sed -n '713p' run21.txt);
```

But it didn't work and give me an error of `ambiguous redirect`. Please, let me know any solution.

Comment: try `< <(sed -n '713p' run21.txt)` it is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: No It didn't wok. comes with error

Comment: no it didn't work. Come with error  syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: Did you leave the `space` in `< <(sed -n '713p' run21.txt)` and get rid of the `$`?? The `space` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, to convert from `hex` to `dec` use `bc` with defined `ibase` and `obase`, e.g.

```
$ echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $(sed -n 713p run21.txt)" | bc
```

Whatever `hex` value is at line `713` will be output as `decimal`. You can use `read -r a b c` to read the 3 values and convert each in a similar manner. Or you can remove the whitespace between the 3 hex values and convert it into a single decimal value depending on your requirements. For example:

```
hexval=""
for i in $(sed -n 713p run21.txt); do
    hexval="$hexval$i"
done
echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $hexval" | bc
```

**Output**

```
8274624
```

---

To convert each separately, you can do:

```
for i in $(sed -n 713p run21.txt); do
    printf " %d" "$(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $i" | bc)"
done
printf "\n"
```

**Output**

```
126 66 192
```

---

As another step in making the conversion more robust, you can (and should) add **validation** of all values read as input. You can do much more validation as to the type of characters read into each variable, but you should at least validate you *read* AND *filled* the number of values you expected. Putting that together, and utilizing `read` to read and *validate* all 3 values, you could do something like the following.

The script takes the *line_to_read* as its first mandatory argument and the `filename` to read from as its second optional argument (it will read from `stdin` by default):

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && {   ## validate line number given
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s line [file (stdin)]\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

test "$1" -eq "$1" &>/dev/null || {  ## test $1 is an integer value
    printf "error: first parameter not an integer '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

fn="$2" ## read from filename as 2nd parameter (or by default from stdin)
test -f "$fn" || fn=/dev/stdin

read -r a b c < <(sed -n "${1}p" "$fn")     ## read each of the values

test -n "$a" -a -n "$b" -a -n "$c" || {     ## validate all 3 vars filled
    printf "error: less than 3 values on line '%s',\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

printf "input : %3x %3x %3x\n" "0x$a" "0x$b" "0x$c" ## output original line
## output line converted from hex to decimal
printf "output: %3d %3d %3d\n" $(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $a" | bc) \
$(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $b" | bc) $(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $c" | bc)
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/3hex.txt
7E 42 C0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash 3hexcvt.sh 1 <dat/3hex.txt
input :  7e  42  c0
output: 126  66 192
```

Comment: With the `for` loop, the output is `8274624` which is `0x7E42C0` if that is what you need. I am unclear if you need to convert each number or if each of the 3 values represents a term in a single number. Can you explain?

Comment: I want to convert three numbers separately.

Comment: See updated answer, last part. Let me know if that is  what you need.

Comment: It converts but first two only not the third one :(

Comment: it converts now it gives me illegal character: ^M
because the file was copied from windows machine. But now its working. Thanks alot

Comment: Sorry, had to run an errand. That's odd, What OS? Mac? (shouldn't matter, but line endings may be causing problems. I'll give you another rewrite using `while read...`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps more straightforward this way...

```
read p q r < <(sed -n '713{p;q}' file);  printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x$p 0x$q 0x$r;
```

Comment: it works but i didn't understand what **"(sed -n '713{p;q}" **doing I know sed but `'{p;q},'` means what.

Comment: if your file is 10,000 lines long, you don't want to scan to the end after printing the 713th line, `q` quits after print.

Answer (score 0):

@David
I did this

```
while read -r p q r; 
  do 

   #printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x$p 0x$q 0x$r; 
   #printf "%d %d %d\n"
   echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $(sed -n 713p run21.txt)" | bc ;

  done
```

But there is no output.

Comment: You are not feeding the loop with any input `:(` Look at my last addition.  You could do `while read -r n; do echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $n" | bc; done < <(sed -n 713p run21.txt)`